# Excel: How to round number to short scale number (10^3n)

Tags: excel, rounding, largenumber

I have a sheet with dynamic numbers in the range of 10<sup>0</sup>-10<sup>133</sup>.

I want to have 1 cell with the number, and then the adjacent cell to say the [short scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) name.

E.g. 248,556,648,100,000 becomes

`248.557` | `Quadrillion`

And 4,718,392,878,298,380,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 becomes

`4.718` | `Undecillion`

I've solved the displayname-part with a table of all the names and their [base -illion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers#Extensions_of_the_standard_dictionary_numbers) as index (`X2:Z51`):

```
=VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(M8)/3;0)-1;$X$2:$Z$51;3;FALSE)
```

`M8` contains the number that I want to convert (**calculated by a formula** with other inputs).

---

**So the question is:** How do I round the number in `M8` to fit the descriptive name?

And a subquestion is, if it's possible/simple to write a custom number format with this instead.

Comment: What about already using your formula - just again? `=M8/10^(ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(M8),0)-2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the number to display by using the following formula:

`=M8/POWER(10;((ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(M8)/3;0)*3)))`

First I find the number of digits with log<sub>10</sub>, then I divide it by 3 and round down to find it's short scale base. Then I multiply by 3 to have the 10<sup>3n</sup><sub>th</sub> power. I divide my number by that power.

E.g.

`248,556,648,100,000 / 10^(floor(14.395/3)*3)`

because 14.395 is between 12 and 15, and it's rounded down, it becomes:

`248,556,648,100,000 / 10^12`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 4th, divisor column to your lookup table next to the short scale name and then use a second `vLookup` to divide.

```
=M8/VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(M8)/3;0)-1;$X$2:$AA$51;4;FALSE)
```

Comment: How does a divisor work, if I don't know how large the number in M8 is?

Comment: You have to know the divisor to choose the correct short scale name.  It's the number you would divide by to get your expected output.

Comment: I don't know the divisor, I have to calculate it.

Comment: Does "value in numerals" sound familiar? That's your divisor.  And your example from the question would be 248.557 billion.

Comment: I solved it by using the following formula: `=M8/POWER(10;((ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(M8)/3;0)*3)))` - But I'm still curious what your solution is about - and no, it doesn't. I'm not very used to the English terms of mathematics though.

Comment: The divisor for billions would be 1,000,000,000 for millions would be 1,000,000 etc.  And your edit to you question still doesn't make it Quadrillion it's now in Trillions.